# How to prevent navigation being blocked while downloading using an IHttpHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

I'm using an `IHttpHandler` to deal with my downloads. It streams out the file.
However, this handler needs to compare a token to one that is stored in the session. Therefore, it uses `IRequiresSessionState`.

The problem is now: as long as `IRequiresSessionState`  is there, the user cannot keep on navigating the website, while a download is running.

Is there maybe a different approach than using a handler, which would solve my problem (I still need to be IIS6 compatible, but if there's a solution for IIS7 only, it would still be okay)?

Note that I cannot change the session check. I have to access the session.

There are so many things in .NET and IIS I have not discovered yet, maybe there is some functionality one could use.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you just redirect the request to another handler with the token in the URL so that it doesn't need to access the session any more?

Comment: Good idea but how can I be sure that the other handler redirected to me and not some user tried to spoof the security system?

Comment: Yes this is a good point. But if you have GUIDs as identifiers for database objects, this is not a problem, you can let users guess the GUIDs you have - they will not be able to :) 
However if this token is just an integer value, my solution would not be safe obviously - curious users may want to try different values in the URL :(